# What's the expected format of a URL when sending a request from a controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

I have a route that looks like this in my Rails app:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: "api" do
    namespace :v1 do
      # snip
      post "my_route", to: "my_controller#my_action"
```

I'm trying to write a controller test for this action:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::MyController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST my_route" do
    it "should respond with a 200 status" do
      post "api/v1/my_route"
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

When I do this, my test fails with a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` error.

What string should I use in my call to `post` so that RSpec correctly matches my route when it simulates the request? (Notice that my controller lives in the `Api::V1` module; I'm not sure whether this makes a difference or not.)

I've tried:

- `"api/v1/my_route"`
- `"/api/v1/my_route"`
- `"v1/my_route"`
- `"/v1/my_route"`
- `"my_route"`
- `"/my_route"`

I get the same error with all of these strings, and I'm not sure what else could possibly be expected.

---

There are many other questions about `UrlGenerationError` in RSpec tests. None of them have helped me because they all seem to use built-in Rails routes, like `:index` or `:create`. I've specified my action and route directly, so I can't rely on quite as much Rails magic.

I believe that if I knew which format RSpec was expecting me to give for the path string I pass to `post`, I'd be able to figure this out very quickly. Unfortunately, I've had a hard time finding the relevant docs. It seems like most of RSpec's documentation is based on showing example tests, and again, since I'm not using much Rails magic, their examples don't show me what I'm supposed to be doing. What is the format for the URL string I'm supposed to use? Can you please point me to the relevant docs?

Comment: Could you post the result of running `rails routes` so we can see what the routes look like?

Comment: @CarlosRamirezIII The relevant route looks like `POST /api/v1/my_route`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller RSpec paths don't expect you to use the routes specified in `config/routes.rb` when simulating requests. Instead, use the method names on the controllers themselves.

In my example, I have this route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: "api" do
    namespace :v1 do
      # snip
      post "my_route", to: "my_controller#my_action"
```

And this controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class MyController
      def my_action
      # snip
```

So the name of the route is `my_route`, and the name of the controller method is `my_action`. In writing the corresponding test case, I need to refer to `my_action`, the method, not `my_route`, the route.

Like so:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::MyController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST my_route" do
    it "should respond with a 200 status" do
      post "my_action"
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

(Although I found this unintuitive at first, it does make sense now that I think about it. It decouples the controller tests from the routes configuration, making the tests less brittle.)